# Roblox UI issue

Tags: user-interface, game-engine, game-development, roblox

I have an issue with centering my UI in Roblox Studio. While it looks centered on any device, I used to scale and anchor to achieve this. However, when I play the game, the Roblox and chat buttons cause the UI to shift downwards slightly. Can you please advise me on how to fix this?

I set the AnchorPoint = {0.5,0.5}, Position = {(0.5,0),(0.5,0)}

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to clearly describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repetition of the tag information followed by the meaningless phrase *UI issue*. Your title should be clear enough to convey meaning about the question to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. For suggestions on how to write a good title (and question), see [ask].

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the problem, plus the relevant pieces of code that would reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanchayan. I see you're experiencing issues with your Roblox Studio UI. To prevent the UI from moving down, enable the IgnoreGuiInset option! The screenshot is provided below. I hope this fixes it!

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35135036)

Comment: @NicolaiReuschling: Which link are you talking about? The image which op can't inline because they have too little reputation?

Answer (score 0):

if anchorPoint = {x,y} position then try setting the anchorpoint to 0. I never use anchorpoint because i use some plugins to scale and anchor gui and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning your UI elements from `Scale` mode to `Offset` mode or do the opposite regarding the mode the element is on.. Even enable `IgnoreGuiInset` which should help.